# Saber quantidade de checkbox selecionados

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Quantos *checkboxes* está sendo selecionados e fazer uma contagem. Selecionou 1, marca 1, selecionou outro marca +1, tirou 1 marca -1. Gostaria de fazer uma contagem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Esse é o código que precisa:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length
```

Se quiser correr a cada vez que um é mudado pode usar assim:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function () {
    var total = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
    alert(total);
});
```

**Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/5fuzV/**
**Documentação: http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/**

Comment: Eu usei seu código, só que ele conta duas vezes. Eu marco um checkbox, e ele me da um alert 2x com o número 1

Comment: @AlissonAcioli alerta 2x? Não. Ele dispara um alert quando a check box muda. Uma a uma...

Comment: aqui ele está dando 2 alert quando seleciono ou desmarco algum.

Comment: @AlissonAcioli em que browser você está?

Comment: Google Chrome .... No alert() está dando duas vezes, mas coloquei um $("#count").html(total) e ele ta fazendo certo, deve ser pq ta pegando o último resultado das 2x

Comment: @AlissonAcioli estranho ele fazer dois alerts. Tem alguma biblioteca carregada que está a fazer um "mask" no input?

Comment: Não. Mas está funcionando como eu quero, sem problemas.

Comment: @Sergio eu fiz uma pergunta no meta porque, fui questionado sobre cópia do seu código se quiser deixar a sua opinião no meta fique a vontade: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1631/6026

Comment: Não deveria ser necessário, mas talvez pelo fato de estar se usando alert() possa estar parecendo algo que de fato não é. Experimenta essa [segunda revisão](http://jsfiddle.net/5fuzV/1/), do mesmo código, e veja se persiste o problema.

Answer (score 6):

Vou deixar uma sugestão de implementação

**HTML**

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="ch" /> Opção</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="ch" /> Opção</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="ch" /> Opção</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="ch" /> Opção</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="ch" /> Opção</label>

<div id="contador" data-value="0">

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
label {display:block;}
#contador[data-value="0"]{
    display:none; /*oculta qdo não houver nenhum selecionado*/
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function () {
    //quantidade de selecionados
    var qt = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;   
    //coloca o atributo para ocultar qdo for 0
    $('#contador').attr('data-value',qt);
    //coloca o resultado na div contador
    $('#contador').text(qt + (qt > 1 ? ' selecionados' : ' selecionado'));
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WsTjc/1/)**

Comment: Nesse codigo como não deixar contar os checkbox que estiveram como "disabled"

Comment: Seria isso http://jsfiddle.net/WsTjc/3/ @FabioHenrique ?

Comment: exato isso mesmo

Answer (score 5):

***Html***

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="4">
<input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="5">    
<div id="checkcount"></div>
```

***Script (Javascript)***

```
var contador = function() {
  var n = $("input:checked").length;
  $("#checkcount").text( n + (n === 1 ? " é" : " são") + " selecionados" );
};
contador(); 
$( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click",contador);
```

***Exemplo:*** [***JsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/UD754/)

*Referência:*

- [:checked Selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

Answer (score 5):

Uma forma simplicada de fazer isso é através da nova propriedade do jQuery, pra isso você precisa adicionar uma classe "chave" nos seus checkbox para poder fazer a verificação:

```
$('.checkbox').prop('checked', true);
$('.checkbox').prop('checked', false);
```

Answer (score 4):

Com [*CSS counters*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters) você pode "definir uma variável" para ser incrementada sempre que uma regra casar. No caso, como você quer contar quantos `<input>` estão com o atributo `:checked` verdadeiro, basta:

```css
input:checked {
  counter-increment: checked-inputs
}

h2::after {
  content: 'Itens marcados: ' counter(checked-inputs)
}
```

```html
<input type='checkbox'>
<input type='checkbox'>
<input type='checkbox'>
<input type='checkbox'>

<h2></h2>
```

```css
input {
  counter-increment: total-items
}

input:checked {
  counter-increment: checked-items total-items
}

h2::after {
  content: counter(checked-items) ' de ' counter(total-items)
}
```

```html
<input type='checkbox'>
<input type='checkbox'>
<input type='checkbox'>
<input type='checkbox'>
<input type='checkbox'>
<input type='checkbox'>
<input type='checkbox'>
<input type='checkbox'>

<h2></h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input {
  counter-increment: total-items
}

input:checked {
  counter-increment: checked-items total-items
}

h2::after {
  content: counter(checked-items) ' de ' counter(total-items)
}
```

teria como utilizar com valor do checkBox que esta no dataTables