# Propriedades counter no CSS. Para que servem e como funcionam?

Tags: css

Recentemente estava estudando CSS e descobri o `counter-reset` e o `counter-increment`, só que não entendi ao certo as propriedades e fiquei com algumas dúvidas.

### **Dúvidas**

1. Para que serve `counter-reset` e o `counter-increment` no CSS?
2. Existe alguma real utilidade para essas propriedades?
3. São suportadas por muitos navegadores?
4. Como elas realmente funcionam?

Comment: Alguma real utilidade [nesse exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/212634/4808) ou [nesse outro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/271732/4808).

Comment: @Renan bem massa o exemplo de uso

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Existem algumas formas bem interessantes de aplicação para os `counter`. Uma é numerar páginas, a outra é numerar itens e sub-itens de uma lista por exemplo. Mas vc pode usar para numerar capítulos de um editorial e seus sub-títulos por exemplo... Outra aplicação simples seria para numerar `divs`, como se elas fossem uma lista ordenada de `divs`.

**Numerando UL e LI**

Primeiro veja esse modelo básico para entender o conceito.

Repare que nele eu inicio o `counter` na `UL`, e no `::after` desse `UL` eu coloco o resultado dentro do `content`. Depois disso eu usa o LI para fazer o incremento do valor do counter. Isso significa que eu vou "contar" quantas `LI` existem no `DOM` com CSS e plotar esse valor no `content` da `UL`.

Agora vc a parte de colocar o número da `LI`. Para isso vc vai colocar no `::after` das LI o mesmo `counter(teste)`, só que como agora ele está em cada `LI` ele vai mostrar índice do próprio elemento.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja o código para entender melhor, deixei os comentários para vc entender melhor.

```css
ul {
    /* inicia o contador aqui */
    counter-reset: teste;
}
ul::after {
    /* vai pegar o que vier do counter-increment das LIs e colocar aqui nesse after */
    content: counter(teste);
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
}
li {
    /* vai contar quantas LI tem no DOM dentro dessa UL */
    counter-increment: teste;
}
li::after {
    /* coloca na LI o próprio número que ela tem no index */
    content: " " counter(teste);
    color: green;
}
```

```html
  <ul>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 2</li>
      <li>item 3</li>
      <li>item 4</li>
      <li>item 5</li>
  </ul>
```

---

**Lista Vazando o Escopo**

Esse tipo de lista é interessante, pq ela "sangra o escopos" do pai e a ordem da lista é compartilhada. O que quero dizer é que temos aqui 3 `OL` e mesmo assim a ordem da contagem é compartilhada entre todas as `LI` como se a `OL` fosse "ignorada". Isso acontece pq iniciamos o counter no `body`, e não na `OL`

Repare que mesmo todas as `OL` tendo algumas `LI` dentro, a sequencia alfabética segue como uma coisa só da primeira `LI` da primeira `OL` até a última `LI` da última `OL`. Por exemplo, o segundo grupo de `LI`s dentro da segunda `OL` começa na letra `D` e não na letra `A`

**OBS:** Eu usei `OL` e `LI`, mas poderiam ser `DIV`s e `P`s tranquilamente *(mas não semanticamente)*

```css
body {
  background: #333;
  counter-reset: mega-step mini-step;
}
ol {
  padding: 0;
}
ol li{
  counter-increment: mini-step;
  list-style:none;
}
ol li:before{
  content:counter(mini-step, lower-alpha) " ";
  background:darkred;
  color:white;
  padding:2px 5px;
  margin: 4px;
  font:14px/250% times new roman;
  border-radius: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

section {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
  background: white;
  counter-increment: mega-step;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  
}
section:before {
  content: counter(mega-step, upper-roman);
  background:white;
  width:30px;
  position: absolute;
  left:0px; top:-20px;
  text-align: center;
  color:darkred;
  font: bold 20px times new roman;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <ol>
    <li>começa no A</li>
    <li>LI 2 da OL 1</li>
    <li>LI 3 da OL 1</li>
  </ol>
</section>

<section>
  <ol>
    <li>Segue com D</li>
    <li>LI 2 da OL 2</li>
    <li>LI 3 da OL 2</li>
  </ol>
</section>

<section>
  <ol>
    <li>LI 1 da OL 3</li>
    <li>LI 2 da OL 3</li>
    <li>Última li de 3 OL = I</li>
  </ol>
</section>
```

Nesse exemplo eu usei `upper-roman` para numerar as Sections com números em Romano **(I)** e `lower-alpha` para ordenar as Kem ordem alfabética **(a)**. Veja que o segundo argumento do `counter` é o estilo usado para no contador.

```
content: counter(mega-step, upper-roman)
content:counter(mini-step, lower-alpha)
```

**DICA:** Aqui tem uma lista completa desse Estilos que vc pode usar no counter, são os mesmo usados tradicionalmente nas *Listas Ordenadas* e *Não Ordenadas*

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type

---

**Veja o exemplo de lista / sub-lista**

Primeiro vc tem que "iniciar" o `Counter` em todos os `<ol>`, e remover o valor default da Lista Ordenada. Depois no `<li>` vc faz o incremento do `Counter` no `Content`. O legal aqui é que vc tem toda a flexibilidade do CSS para customizar seus números etc. ***OBS:*** Deixei os comentário no código do CSS

```css
ol {
    counter-reset: section;  /* inicia um contador com valor 0 nome de "section" */             
    list-style-type: none;   /* remove o valor default da <ol> */ 
}

li::before {
    counter-increment: section; /* inclui o contado "section" com incremento de 1 */          
    content: counters(section, "-") ": ";  /* pega o valor do counter do pai e coloca um "-" depois da um espaço com os ": " e coloca o valor do counter do filho */
    color: red;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: sans-serife;
}

.custom-counter {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <ol class="custom-counter">
        <li><b>RESUMO DE ATIVIDADES</b>
            <ol class="custom-counter">
                <li><b>SUB ATIVIDADES</b></li>
                <li><b>SUB ATIVIDADES</b></li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li><b>COMENTÁRIOS</b>
            <ol class="custom-counter">
                <li><b>SUB COMENTÁRIOS</b></li>
                <li><b>SUB COMENTÁRIOS</b></li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

---

**Exemplo numerando `divs` de 2 em dois como o incremento de 2 dentro do `counter-increment`**

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    counter-increment: nDiv 2; /* começa o contador a partir de 2 e vai somando 2 a cada incremento */
}

div::before {
    content: counter(nDiv); /* mostra o valor do contador */
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

---

**Aqui tem um exemplo de aplicação para fazer numeração de páginas:**

```
  @page {
    size: A4;  
    margin: 70pt 60pt 170pt;
    counter-increment: page;
    @bottom-center {
      content: "Page " counter(page);
    }
  }
```

Exemplo de como começar a contagem por um determinado número em uma determinada página.

```
 @page { counter-increment: page } @page:first { counter-reset: page 9 }
```

A combinação de ambas as regras irá redefinir o contador para da primeira página para 9. Então, para cada página (incluindo a primeira), ela incrementará o contador. Isso resulta em um valor de contador de 10 para a primeira página, 11 para o segundo e assim por diante.

*Fonte:* https://www.tallcomponents.com/blog/css3-page-counter

---

**Sobre o suporte dos browsers**

Counter é uma propriedade relativamente antiga e amplamente aceita, até o IE8 já tem suporte para ela como vc pode consultar aqui: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-counters

**Referência e documentação**

Aqui vc pode ler mais sobre o `Counter` https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters

Comment: Exemplo customizando Caracteres pré-definidos para a lista, tipo uma lista de JSON no CSS `@counter-style sua-lista {
  system: cyclic;
 symbols: "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "☺️" "" "" "";
 suffix: "  ";
}` https://codepen.io/argyleink/pen/rNmzGzW

Answer (score 5):

A propriedade `counter-reset` cria ou redefine um contador de CSS para um determinado valor.

A propriedade `counter-increment` faz o valor do contador ser aumentado ou diminuído.

**Veja o exemplo**, onde digo que `meu_contador` tem valor inicial 0, e depois de cada ocorrência é sempre incrementado +1. Note que o `::before` permite inserir conteúdo antes de um elemento, neste caso antes de um item da lista. A propriedade `content` é para dizer ao navegador que o conteúdo deve ser colocado no início do elemento HTML.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      /* definindo "meu_contador"  como 0 */
      counter-reset: meu_contador 0;
    }
    
    h2::before {
      /* Incrementado "meu_contador" como 1 */
      counter-increment: meu_contador 1;
      content: "Fruta " counter(meu_contador) ": ";
      color: black;
    }
    
    h1 {
      color: orange;
    }
    
    h2 {
      color: green;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Lista de frutas:</h1>
  <h2>Uva </h2>
  <h2>Maçã</h2>
  <h2>Jabuticaba</h2>
  <h2>Pêra</h2>
  <h2>Banana</h2>
  <h2>Laranja</h2>

</body>

</html>
```

**Sintaxes:**

### - **counter-increment:**

```
counter-increment: <custom-ident> <integer>
```

Onde:

- `<custom-ident>`:

  É o nome do contador para incrementar.
- `<integer>`:

  É o valor para adicionar ao contador.Se não forem especificados o valor padrão é 1.

**Exemplo:**  `counter-increment: exemplo_contador 2;`

### - **counter-reset:**

```
counter-reset: <custom-ident> <integer>
```

Onde:

- `<custom-ident>`:

  É nome do contador para redefinir.
- `<integer>`:

  É o valor para redefinir o contador em cada ocorrência do elemento.  Se não forem especificados o valor padrão é 0.

**Exemplo:**  `counter-reset: exemplo_contador 1;`

A [imagem](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_counter-reset.asp) abaixo mostra a versão dos navegadores que suportam totalmente a propriedade:

[image: Versão dos navegadores que suportam a propriedade]

***Referência:***

[MDN Web Docs](http://MDN%20Web%20Docs)

[W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_counter-reset.asp)

Comment: Muito boa resposta! Obrigado por compartilhar :)