# Paginação com Owl Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, owl-carousel

Estou tentando fazer com um formato de paginação com o owl carousel, fiz conforme [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823571/how-to-get-total-and-current-slide-number-of-carousel), mas não consegui fazer passar disso.

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.css">
    <style type="text/css">
    .num{
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    padding:10px;
    width:50px;
    text-align:center;
}
  </style>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid p-0">
 <div class="row no-gutters">
  <div class="col-12">
   <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item" data-dot="<button>01</button>">
     <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/800/?random"> 
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-dot="<button>02</button>">
     <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/800/?random"> 
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-dot="<button>02</button>">
     <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/800/?random"> 
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-dot="<button>02</button>">
     <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/800/?random"> 
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-dot="<button>02</button>">
     <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/800/?random"> 
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="num"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
            loop:true,
            autoplay:true,
            autoplayTimeout:5000,
            margin:0,
            nav:true,
            dots: false,
            mouseDrag: false,
            items:1
        });
var items = $('.owl-item').length;
var cloned = $('.owl-item.cloned').length;
var totalItems = items - cloned;
var currentIndex = $('div.active').index() + 1;


$('.num').html(''+currentIndex+'/'+totalItems+'');

    </script>
```

Comment: qual é exatamente a sua dúvida?

Comment: Valeu Lucas, se tiver algum problema com esse código é só comentar na Resposta que te ajudo, mas testei aqui e funcionou perfeito, é só ir colocando os slides que ele soma sozinho :D Tb coloquei uma resposta lá na outra Pergunta do Emoji, depois olha lá

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vou te dar uma resposta apenas com CSS a primeira parte dela é baseada nessa pergunta [Propriedades counter no CSS. Para que servem e como funcionam?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/332330/propriedades-counter-no-css-para-que-servem-e-como-funcionam) e mas basicamente ela usa a propriedade counter do CSS para contar quantas `LI imagens` vc tem dentro de um *container* e qual delas está ativa.

Primeiro veja esse modelo básico para entender o conceito.

Repare que nele eu inicio o `counter` na `UL`, e no `::after` desse `UL` eu coloco o resultado dentro do `content`. Depois disso eu usa o LI para fazer o incremento do valor do counter. Isso significa que eu vou "contar" quantas `LI` existem no `DOM` com CSS e plotar esse valor no `content` da `UL`.

Agora vc a parte de colocar o número da `LI`. Para isso vc vai colocar no `::after` das LI o mesmo `counter(teste)`, só que como agora ele está em cada `LI` ele vai mostrar índice do próprio elemento.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja o código para entender melhor, deixei os comentários para vc entender melhor.

```css
ul {
    /* inicia o contador aqui */
    counter-reset: teste;
}
ul::after {
    /* vai pegar o que vier do counter-increment das LIs e colocar aqui nesse after */
    content: counter(teste);
    font-weight: bold;
    color: red;
}
li {
    /* vai contar quantas LI tem no DOM dentro dessa UL */
    counter-increment: teste;
}
li::after {
    /* coloca na LI o próprio número que ela tem no index */
    content: " " counter(teste);
    color: green;
}
```

```html
  <ul>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 2</li>
      <li>item 3</li>
      <li>item 4</li>
      <li>item 5</li>
  </ul>
```

---

**Aplicando ao OWL Carousel**

Agora que vc entendeu o conceito vamos para prática, tomei como base [esse exemplo](https://codepen.io/jovanivezic/pen/JXWOex).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então partindo dessa ideia, vc consegue enumerar individualmente cada `LI` pelo seu índice, e também pegar o número total de `LIs` dentro da `UL`, e é isso que vc vai usar para contar os slides tipo **`1 de 5`** no seu OWL Caroucel.

Repare que o CSS só mostra o Index do item que tb tem a classe `.active`. Além disso, vc precisa estilizar os estilos originas dos `Dots` para usa-los para mostrar a contagem dos itens.

Segue o modelo funcionando.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">

    <style>

    .owl-item {
        background-color: #D2527F;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 60px 0;
    }

    .owl-prev {
        float: left;
        font-size: 20px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        padding: 20px;
    }

    .owl-next {
        float: right;
        font-size: 20px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        padding: 20px;
    }

    .owl-dots {
        counter-reset: slides-num;
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-top: 15px;
    }
    .owl-dots::after {
        content: counter(slides-num);
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 700;
        vertical-align: middle;
        padding-left: 15px;
    }

    .owl-dot {
        display: inline-block;
        counter-increment: slides-num;
        margin-right: 5px;
    }
    .owl-dot span {
        display: none;
    }
    .owl-dot.active::before {
        content: counter(slides-num) " de";
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        font-size: 20px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
    }

    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="owl-carousel">
        <div> Slide 1 </div>
        <div> Slide 2 </div>
        <div> Slide 3 </div>
        <div> Slide 4 </div>
        <div> Slide 5 </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
            margin:10,
            loop:true,
            dots: true,
            nav: true,
            items: 1
    });    
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```